# Why is iftop using so much memory? Are there any tools that are powerful, but do not use so much memory?

Tags: linux, iftop

```
pmap iftop_id
```

```
b7fce000      4K rw---  /lib/ld-2.5.so
bf9aa000     84K rw---    [ stack ]
 total   204940K
```

The memory of the server is only 1GB, but `iftop` takes 204MB. It is crazy that `iftop` uses so much memory - why? Are there any tools that are similarly powerful, but do not use so much memory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Dropbox use so much memory on Linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/470947/why-does-dropbox-use-so-much-memory-on-linux)

Answer (score 0):

You may find something useful here.

http://linuxaria.com/article/monitor-your-bandwidth-from-the-linux-shell?lang=en